# Selenium chromedriver crashes on some test runs

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a set of python Selenium tests that run on chromedriver, and I've found that certain tests will fail occasionally because chromedriver crashes.

If chromedriver crashes during one of my tests it's almost always at the same spot in that test, but I've looked at the tests and there doesn't seem to be anything that would cause the crash. Often it's just a link click that seems to cause it.

I can run the same test twice and one time it will pass, the other time it will fail because chromedriver crashes.

I'm running the latest version of the selenium standalone server (2.18.0), Chrome version 17 and python version 2.7.1.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 2.19 is out. Some code, crash info ?

Comment: I've updated to use 2.19, and I'm still having the same problems. Not getting any crash info either, the chrome window just crashes (I see the Aw Snap page) and eventually my test will timeout.

Comment: The console output from the selenium server. Does it crash or only the browser? Feel free to go to #selenium on freenode.

Comment: Is it python related maybe? Have you tried it in Java?

Comment: It's just the browser that crashes, and I've done some debugging, it looks like it's not even clicking something that causes it to crash. It seems to crash after I've clicked a link and the new page has loaded. Could it be just that the page I'm loading is ajax heavy and chromedriver can't handle it?

Answer (score 1):

What often happens in chromedriver is that when an element is not in the visible region (for example if there vertical scroll bars and the web element is not in the region) the driver will throw Element not clickable error, which is essentially saying that the element you are trying to click is not currently visible to the user although it is present in the DOM. Ie and FF do not has this issue because they auto scroll to the focused web element.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try to move the mouse pointer to 0,0 coordinates. Because click event is not as reliable as the one in firefox.